# TSQL - IF... then else and case on Dates

Tags: t-sql, date

Am having a brain freeze...

I have 4 status dates i.e. when the status was changed on a client record and I need to then query the data and find at what status the client was at a particular date.

e.g. Data

Client  Setup Date  Live Date  Closing Date  Closed Date

0001 01/01/12 10/01/12 23/02/12 15/11/12

0002        08/10/12   11/11/12

0003        11/12/12

So for a date of 31/12/12 then 0001 would indicate a status of closed, 0002 would be Live, 0003 would be Setup.

I want to return only the Client and Status for that date.

So on 31/12/12 I would get a result of 
0001 Closed
0002 Live
0003 Setup

I tried this using a case but it's gone wrong somewhere as it seems to be returning me the same status and I can see why it doesn't work but my little noggin can't work out a way to get it to work. This is coming from another query that extracts and inserts into a #Temp table.

```
CASE 
WHEN #TempOutput.[System Setup] BETWEEN @Start and @End THEN 'Prospect' 
WHEN #TempOutput.[Prospect to Live] BETWEEN @Start and @End THEN 'Live'
WHEN #TempOutput.[Live to Terminal] BETWEEN @Start and @End THEN 'Terminal'
WHEN #TempOutput.Closing BETWEEN @Start and @End THEN 'Closed'
END
```

This is like the first step as I then need to loop through this to show what the status was of each client over a period. So if it's a weekly period then it needs to loop through 52 times based on an entry date... I can do this bit! LOL

any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Client,
CASE 
   WHEN [Closed] <= @GivenDate THEN 'Closed'
   WHEN [Closing] <= @GivenDate THEN 'Closing'
   WHEN [Live to Terminal] <= @GivenDate THEN 'Terminal'
   WHEN [Prospect to Live] <= @GivenDate THEN 'Live'
   ELSE 'Prospect' 
END Status
FROM #TempOutput
WHERE [System Setup] <= @GivenDate
```

Comment: Oh hell.. wrong way round! Knew it was something simple like that! You are a legend!!!!!!!! Thanks

Comment: Did I mention I love you! :o)

Comment: Wow, nick `user1966849` loves me! :)